# Query does not run

Tags: php, select, mysqli, union

i am trying to use union to join two mysqli queries using the same table. it works fine if i run the sql on phpmyadmin  but cannot work if i run it under php script. I am doing something wrong?

```
  <?php
    $query = $db->query ("Select(select *, GREATEST(MAX(totadyo1), MAX(totadyo2), MAX(totadyo3), MAX(totadyo4), MAX(totadyo5)) as HIGH, MIN(totadyo1), MIN(totadyo2),
     MIN(totadyo3), MIN(totadyo4), MIN(totadyo5) as LOW from adult_rpt a LEFT JOIN oldgroup2 ON a.oldgroup_id = oldgroup2.oldgroup_id 
     LEFT JOIN group2 ON a.group_id = group2.group_id LEFT JOIN district2 ON a.district_id = district2.district_id where service = 'sws' 
     and month = 'jan' group by district_name)

        UNION
            (select *, totadyo1,totadyo2,totadyo3,totadyo4,totadyo5, Case When totadyo1 < totadyo2 And totadyo1 < totadyo3
               And totadyo1 < totadyo4 And totadyo1 < totadyo5 Then totadyo1 When totadyo2 < totadyo1 And totadyo2 < totadyo3 And 
               totadyo2 < totadyo4 And totadyo2 < totadyo5 Then totadyo2 When totadyo3 < totadyo1 And totadyo3 < totadyo2 And 
               totadyo3 < totadyo4 And totadyo3 < totadyo5 Then totadyo3 When totadyo4 < totadyo1 And totadyo4 < totadyo2 And 
               totadyo4 < totadyo3 And totadyo4 < totadyo5 Then totadyo4 Else totadyo5 End As LOW from adult_rpt a LEFT 
               JOIN oldgroup2 ON a.oldgroup_id = oldgroup2.oldgroup_id LEFT JOIN group2 ON a.group_id = group2.group_id LEFT 
               JOIN district2 ON a.district_id = district2.district_id where service = 'sws' and month = 'jan' group by district_name)")
               or die(mysqli_error($query));
```

Comment: you have syntax errors here and you're mixing apis and using the wrong variable on top of that.

Comment: You have too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: if you just want results in 1 array then just merge the results from both queries otherwise it just looks messy now

Comment: Mixing `mysql_error` with `mysqli` functions... that is going to increase the confusion for sure. String is not closed correctly (the automatic syntax highlighting in question already shows that it is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your comments, especially Joshkisb. After going through the code again, I resulted into merging the 2 queries together and remove the union and bravo! it works fine.

```
<?php
            $query = $db->query("select *, GREATEST(MAX(totadyo1), MAX(totadyo2), MAX(totadyo3), MAX(totadyo4), MAX(totadyo5)) as HIGH,
        totadyo1,totadyo2,totadyo3,totadyo4,totadyo5, Case When totadyo1 < totadyo2 And totadyo1 < totadyo3
           And totadyo1 < totadyo4 And totadyo1 < totadyo5 Then totadyo1 When totadyo2 < totadyo1 And totadyo2 < totadyo3 And 
           totadyo2 < totadyo4 And totadyo2 < totadyo5 Then totadyo2 When totadyo3 < totadyo1 And totadyo3 < totadyo2 And 
           totadyo3 < totadyo4 And totadyo3 < totadyo5 Then totadyo3 When totadyo4 < totadyo1 And totadyo4 < totadyo2 And 
           totadyo4 < totadyo3 And totadyo4 < totadyo5 Then totadyo4 Else totadyo5 End As LOW from adult_rpt  a
        LEFT JOIN oldgroup2 ON a.oldgroup_id = oldgroup2.oldgroup_id 
        LEFT JOIN group2 ON a.group_id = group2.group_id 
        LEFT JOIN district2 ON a.district_id = district2.district_id where teacher_id='$session_id' and service = 'sws' and month = 'jan' group by district_name
        ORDER BY a.report_id DESC") or die(mysqli_error());
```